# How to set uid for every sever request?

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest, httprequest, analytics, web-analytics

I work in web analytics. We are using both [server logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_log) and client side data (collecting user interaction information using javascript plugin) to get more accurate data, For finding repeat visitors we are using `uid`

Client side we are generating the `uid` and set in the cookie as same as [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/). We must store the `uid` in the server logs so that we can track the user both ways (using server logs and client side data) and merge the data for better analysis.

How do I send the `uid` which is generated in the client side to the server to save the `uid` in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

GA sets a first party cookie so it's uid will be stored in their cookie and it will be available to your server in the headers on every request to your server.  If you are doing it "the same as GA" as you say, then your own client-side tracking would also be setting a first party cookie. So you can make an ajax request to your server after GA code is popped if you want it more immediately, or just wait until the next server request to grab the data from the cookie.

But IMO the simpler solution would be to make the client-side code sync up with the server-side code instead of the other way around.  Pass your server-side generated uid to the client-side code and have your client-side code use that uid.